# How can I load an IPersistFile from memory?

Tags: com, memory-mapped-files, ifilter, ipersistfile

I'm using IPersistFile in C# to load a file, before reading it as an IFilter:

```
IFilter filter = LoadIFilter (fileextension);
IPersistFile persistFile = (filter as IPersistFile);
if (persistFile != null) {
    persistFile.Load (fileName, 0);
    IFILTER_FLAGS flags;
    IFILTER_INIT iflags = IFILTER_INIT.FILTER_OWNED_VALUE_OK;
    if (filter.Init (iflags, 0, IntPtr.Zero, out flags) == IFilterReturnCode.S_OK) {
        return filter; // will be read using GetChunk/GetText
    }
}
```

This works fine.

However, I would like to load the file contents from memory instead of a disk path. Is that possible? The IPersistFile interface does not show any other way than providing a path string, so it seems neither a memory mapped file nor a byte array can be used.

Answer (score 1):

As a preleminary answer sketch: My research [indicates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965717%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that it might be possible to cast to [IPersistStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690091%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of IPersistFile, which allows loading from an IStream and thus from a memory target.

Comment: Yes, all sane `IFilter` implementation should implement `IPersistStream` and you can just try to query `IPersistStream` and use it.

Comment: @sharptooth Thanks, I see. So an IFilter should implement as many IPersistX interfaces as possible to be usable in all situations.

Comment: Well, not really, the minimum seems to be `IFilter`, `IPersistFile` and `IPersistStream`.

Comment: Be aware, some iFilters ONLY support one of the IPersist* interfaces. Windows Search uses the IPersistStream interface on iFilters, but does not use IPersistFile. And ifilttst uses IPersistFile. Some manufacturers only implement one to limit their usability on purpose.